# SHA1 Verification Function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, sha, hashlib

My professor recently posted an example function for us to use, that checks an in put, in this case "name", and runs several tests to to either return true or false. However he kind of threw us in the deep end in understanding why it does what it does. I understand individually what the actual lines do, but I dont understand why they do them, so if it could be explained to me why each line does what it does it would be greatly appreciated. How is this SHA1 verification?

```
import hashlib

def enc_check(name):
    hash = hashlib.sha1()
    for i in xrange(10):
        hash.update(name[i::10])
        dig = map(ord, hash.digest())
        if sum(dig[::2]) != sum(dig[1::2]) or sum(dig[:len(dig)/2]) != sum(dig[len(dig)/2:]):
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing about this function makes any kind of actual sense. If you understand the individual lines, you're not missing some deeper meaning.

It basically seems to be a test to find some special value that exhibits a difficult to achieve set of properties, specifically that if you take every tenth character from the input starting from index 0, then every tenth from index 0 followed by every tenth from index 1, and so on and so on until you've got the complete data from indexes in this order: 0, 10, ... 10n, 1, 11, ..., 10n+1, 2, 12, ..., 10n+2, ......, 9, 19, ..., 10n+9, that *each* of those 10 progressively larger strings will have a hash where:

1. The sum of the even bytes is the same as the sum of the odd bytes, and
2. The sum of the first half of the bytes is the same as the sum of the last half.

I don't know the precise odds of both conditions holding true for all 10 hashes, but it can't be very high. I assume your professor has some example that meets the criteria, but I don't know what they expect you to make of this nonsense.

Comment: So i assume he is trying to show us a pattern of some sort, is there a particular reason you can think of for this?, or is this just a super specific example test case?, since apparently there is no deeper meaning I am missing, we just add the chars that make up the hash, and as long as they meet those two criteria its true end of story? nothing else?

Comment: @zavier: No reasonable pattern I can think of. A cryptographically secure hash algorithm should have every output bit dependent on every input bit & the distribution of the bits should be essentially random; while using incomplete hashes doesn't preserve these guarantees fully, I don't know of any means shy of brute force to find a string that meets these arcane criteria. SHA-1 has [weaknesses against length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Cryptanalysis_and_validation), so brute forcing a string to meet the criteria may be practical, but I have no idea why you'd bother.

Comment: thank you for your help I really appreciate it!, there must be something I misunderstood at some point from him because this is too specific I will make sure to ask, at least now I know there was no hidden meaning and I am actually somewhat knowledgeable